# Pass parameter value to sql file from batch file using batch command

Tags: sql, batch-file, parameters, parameter-passing, command-prompt

I have a sql file `update_qde.sql`
which contains the following code

```
UPDATE profile_const
set parameter_value = '04_2015'
where profile_name = 'MIDAS_MTH_ALL_Panels'
and parameter_name = 'PERIODS_TO';
commit;

quit;
```

I have another batch file `test.bat`

I want to pass the parameter_value as a variable from a batch file using batch command.

Could you please show me any way to do this?

Comment: this may help you : [Passing parameters to SQL script using batch files](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ssehgal/archive/2009/04/03/passing-parameters-to-sql-script-using-batch-files.aspx)

Comment: Thanks. Will check and let you know

Answer (score 4):

Use SQLCMD variables, so change test.bat to call SQLCMD rather than ISQL

```
@echo off
sqlcmd -E -S myserver -i update_qde.sql -v PARM1=2015-01-01
```

Change the SQL to use the $() notation

```
UPDATE profile_const
SET parameter_value = '$(PARM1)'
WHERE profile_name = 'MIDAS_MTH_ALL_Panels'
AND parameter_name = 'PERIODS_TO';
COMMIT;
```

Answer (score 1):

Its pretty simple.

Create a batch file with the below 3 line of code. To create a batch file, create a new `.txt` file, save the below code inside the file and rename the extension of this file from `.txt` to `.bat`.

In the 2nd line below code `value1` is the variable name which holds the value you need to update. Third line of code is where you will pass this variable value to the sql file.

```
@echo off    
SET value1=04_2015    
sqlplus db_username/db_password@db_schema @sample.sql %value1%
```

The code for `sample.sql` is given below. The `&&1` in the below code accepts the parameter that you are sending from the batch file and will be stored in the variable `param1`. Later you can use this `param1` variable inside the `BEGIN` block to be used for `UPDATE` query.

```
SET SERVEROUTPUT ON
SET DEFINE ON
SET NEWPAGE 0
SET SPACE 0
SET LINESIZE 200
SET PAGESIZE 0
SET ECHO OFF
SET FEEDBACK OFF
SET HEADING OFF
SET MARKUP HTML OFF SPOOL OFF
SET term off 
SET verify off
set echo off
SPOOL "C:\Test\Logfile.log" append;

var param1 VARCHAR2(20);
BEGIN
:param1 := '&&1';   
END;
/

SET DEFINE OFF

BEGIN

    UPDATE profile_const
    set parameter_value = :param1
    where profile_name = 'MIDAS_MTH_ALL_Panels'
    and parameter_name = 'PERIODS_TO';
    commit;     

END;
/

quit;
/

SPOOL OFF;
SET DEFINE ON
SET SERVEROUTPUT OFF
```

I verified the above code, which works fine.